# Permission denied, when run pyspark2 from user root

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera

I was trying to run pyspark2 from user=root, but I'm getting permission denied error. Haven't got idea why this error happens.

```
[root@quickstart cloudera]# pyspark2
env: /usr/local/bin: Permission denied
```

I gave 777 access to this folder /usr/local/bin. Didn't help.

```
[root@quickstart cloudera]# ls -la /usr/local/bin
total 19636
drwxrwxrwx.  3 root root    4096 Dec  5 01:33 .
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root    4096 Sep 19 05:40 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     101 Nov  5 07:29 2to3-3.6
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     242 Jun 29 07:44 easy_install-3.6
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root      99 Nov  5 07:29 idle3.6
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root    1675 Dec  5 01:33 jp.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     216 Nov  5 07:43 pip
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     216 Nov  5 07:43 pip3
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     216 Nov  5 07:43 pip3.6
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root    4096 Dec  5 01:33 __pycache__
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root      84 Nov  5 07:29 pydoc3.6
-rwxrwxrwx   2 root root 9998398 Nov  5 07:28 python3.6
-rwxrwxrwx   2 root root 9998398 Nov  5 07:28 python3.6m
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root    3103 Nov  5 07:29 python3.6m-config
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     441 Nov  5 07:29 pyvenv-3.6
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     714 Dec  5 01:33 rst2html4.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root    1139 Dec  5 01:33 rst2html5.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     594 Dec  5 01:33 rst2html.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     791 Dec  5 01:33 rst2latex.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     600 Dec  5 01:33 rst2man.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root    1698 Dec  5 01:33 rst2odt_prepstyles.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     764 Dec  5 01:33 rst2odt.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     601 Dec  5 01:33 rst2pseudoxml.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     637 Dec  5 01:33 rst2s5.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     871 Dec  5 01:33 rst2xetex.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     602 Dec  5 01:33 rst2xml.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     670 Dec  5 01:33 rstpep2html.py
```

When I try to run pyspark - It works and runs pyspark 1.6 defauls shell.

```
[root@quickstart cloudera]# pyspark 
WARNING: User-defined SPARK_HOME (/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.3-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.2/lib/spark) overrides detected (/usr/lib/spark). 
WARNING: Running pyspark from user-defined location. Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
```

I tried to set env variables, but it didn't resolve the issue, even pyspark for 1.6 gives me permission denied error:

```
SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2

[root@quickstart cloudera]# pyspark
env: /usr/local/bin: Permission denied
```

Also I tried to export, but no luck:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.6
PYTHONPATH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python:/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/build:
```

My env is:

- CDH 5.13.3
- Python 3.6
- Default centos 6.7 with python 2.6.6
- Spark 1.6
- Spark2 2.3.0

Comment: I dont know how quickstart VM is set up, but can you try `sudo -u hive pyspark2`, with "hive" or any other user that have access to hdfs?